# .sln-compatible Mono-based CLI build system?

Tags: mono, makefile, command-line-interface, solution, build-system

I've recently begun doing ASP.NET MVC work with others using Visual Studio. While MonoDevelop can open their project workspace files (.sln from MSVS2010) and build the projects just fine, I'm curious if there's a CLI build tool I can use with Mono? I'd like to simply use vim and switch into my shell and run a simple command to build the workspace. Any ideas if this has been factored out?

As an added bonus, anybody know if ctags or a similar plugin works on vim? I still have to look up .NET namespace documentation from time to time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use MonoDevelop's building support from the command line, use:

```
mdtool build myproject.sln
```

There is also an implementation of msbuild:

```
xbuild myproject.sln
```